# Print only the first match once

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a code snippet that I am using to parse through a log file and print information I need.

```
for i in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2"); do
        grep "$1" ~/jlog/"$2" |
        awk '/\([a-zA-Z0-9.]+/ {print $7}' 
 done;
```

The problem is when I enter input in, it displays the answer multiple times:

```
(1.3.51.0.1.1.10.10.30.48.2084865.2084839/1.2.840.113619.2.284.3.17454802.933.1401109176.280.1)
(1.3.51.0.1.1.10.10.30.48.2084865.2084839/1.2.840.113619.2.284.3.17454802.933.1401109176.283.1)
(1.3.51.0.1.1.10.10.30.48.2084865.2084839/1.2.840.113619.2.80.977011700.14346.1401109696.2)
(1.3.51.0.1.1.10.10.30.48.2084865.2084839/1.2.840.113619.2.80.977011700.14346.1401109706.51)
(1.3.51.0.1.1.10.10.30.48.2084865.2084839/1.2.840.113619.2.80.977011700.14346.1401109758.100)
(1.3.51.0.1.1.10.10.30.48.2084865.2084839/1.2.840.113619.2.80.977011700.14346.1401109773.149)
(1.3.51.0.1.1.10.10.30.48.2084865.2084839/1.2.840.113619.2.80.977011700.14346.1401109810.198)
(1.3.51.0.1.1.10.10.30.48.2084865.2084839/1.2.840.113619.2.80.977011700.14346.1401109818.247)
```

Is there any way I can trim this so I can only have the first series of data display once. I only need `1.3.51.0.1.1.10.10.30.48.2084865.2084839` to print out once.

I tried to change it to this as well, but Bash does not like it:

```
for i in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2"); do
        grep "$1" ~/jlog/"$2" |
        awk '/\([a-zA-Z0-9.]+/' |
        awk -F'[(/]' ' {print $2, exit}'
done;
```

Then tried this:

```
for i in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2"); do
        grep "$1" ~/jlog/"$2" |
        awk -F'[(/]' '/\([a-zA-Z0-9.]+/ {print $2, exit }'
done;
```

Comment: @JorgeCastro Why did you vote to close this as off-topic? (at least it looks like you did).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this,

```
for i in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2"); do
        grep "$1" ~/jlog/"$2" |
        awk '/\([a-zA-Z0-9.]+/ {print $7; exit}' 
done;
```

`exit` in the awk command exits after printing the first match.

OR

Just pipe the output of `for` command to the below awk command,

```
for .... | awk -F'[(/]' '{print $2;exit}'
```

Comment: Maybe using `uniq` would be more appropriate

Comment: I will try both options. The script takes quite a few minutes to run because the log files I will be looking at are big.

Comment: @ryekayo may i know what are you trying to achieve from the log file?

Comment: I am looking for a unique code. It's something I am doing for my boss. It is imbedded in our log files.

Comment: @ryekayo see my update.

Comment: I tried this `for i in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2"); do
                grep "$1" ~/jlog/"$2" |
                awk '/\([a-zA-Z0-9.]+/' |
                awk -F'[(/]' ' {print $2, exit}'
        done;
`. It did not like it..Sorry for the mess.

Comment: did you fed the for output to awk command(mentioned at second)?

Comment: yes i did, it is actually shown in the code snippet I placed in the comment. I will update my question to show you. I know the convention in the comment is hideous lol

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `for` loop - a single call `grep` will output all the matching lines from the file, so you're just repeating the same operation over and over for as many times as there are lines in the file.

Technically, you don't need both `awk` and `grep` either since both can do textual matching. If you want a more specific answer then post an extract of the log file and an example of what output you want.

Comment: I can't do that, some of the information in our logs is sensitive.

Comment: @ryekayo not the exact one. But a sample like original.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained what you're actually doing so I'll make a couple of assumptions. I assume you're running a script called `foo.sh` and giving it a string and a file name as an argument. These then become `$1` and `$2` respectively. Presumably, you are running it with something similar to

```
foo.sh SearchPattern LogFileName
```

In any case, the `for` loop is i) completely useless since you're not using the `i` variable created by the `for i in ...` loop. ii) very wrong since that will make `i` take the value of each *word* and not the entire line which is what you were probably thinking of iii) the cause of all your problems. You're getting the same results multiple times because you are running the exact same command multiple times. You'll get one result for each line of your file.

Anyway, what you want can be done with something as simple as

```
grep "$1" ~/jlog/"$2" | awk '/\([a-zA-Z0-9.]+/ {print $7}'
```

Or, simpler:

```
awk '/'"$1"'/\([a-zA-Z0-9.]+/ {print $7}' ~/jlog/"$2"
```

The `awk` note that the `"$1"` is not within the single quotes. This makes bash expand it to whatever is currently held in `$1` before it is passed to `awk`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix alot of the errors in the script and it is working almost the way I need it to now.

Comment: @ryekayo that loop will simply make it take 3 times more time than necessary and is not helping you in any way. It is not even being used by your script. Come into chat if you like and I can help out some more.